# How to make this function where I can give it an argument or not

Tags: python-3.6

So I made this very small function. it is a bonehead easy function but frankly borderline my capabilities.. Im learning. The function works as expected, but I would like to go further.  I would like to make it so I can either give it an argument (a username) and just get the information for that single user, or default to reporting all users. is this possible w/o starting over from what I have so far?

I have just poked around and seen some examples but nothing that I can fit into my script. that I can understand at least.

```
import boto3

iam = boto3.client('iam')

def user_group():
    for myusers in iam.list_users()['Users']:
        Group = iam.list_groups_for_user(UserName=myusers['UserName'])
        print("User: "  + myusers['UserName'])
        for groupName in Group['Groups']:
            print("Group: " + groupName['GroupName'])
        print("----------------------------")
user_group()
```

I would like to have the ability to run this script in two fashions.

1) add an argument(s) of 'username' so I can get the response for a particular user

2) default to getting response for all users if no argument is given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by using an argument with a default value:

```
def user_group(user = None):
    if user is None:
        print("No user")
    else:
        print(user)

user_group()
user_group('some user')
```

prints

```
No user
some user
```

In your case you may want to write

```
def user_group(user = None):
    users_to_list = iam.list_users()['Users'] if user is None else [user]
    for myusers in user_to_list:
        ...
```

Comment: ok.. I see the structure.. I am having a hard time figuring out how to integrate with my script though.

Comment: I have updated my answer with the code you would need to either list a single user (user not None) or all users (user is None).